# Java Regex: check if URL is of facebook profile or page

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if the string is the URL of facebook using java regex.
for eg: facebook.com/username

it should also match if it is with the protocol http or https
    http://www.facebook.com/xyz
https://www.facebook.com/xyz

or without protocol also
www.facebook.com/xyz

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wouldn't use regex, create a new [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and use [getHost](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getHost%28%29) to get the hostname and check if its ok for you. (also can check the other URL information)

```
if (!urlString.startsWith("http")) {
    urlString = "http://" + urlString;
}
String hostname = new URL(urlString).getHost();
```

If you insist on using regex you can use the following:

```
String regex = "((http|https)://)?(www[.])?facebook.com/.+";
someURL.matches(regex);
```

Should match any combination of `http`/`https` with or without `www`

Comment: Updated my answer with regex as well

Comment: yes it works but one problem, when I enter "http://www.facebook.com/"  it returns true, as there no username after .com/

Comment: i misunderstood you, changed the * to +